# Page speed very low reason of broken images

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

My site is very very low. I tried this code and fail. How can i fix it, help me please.
Page load time is 56 sec.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
RewriteRule .*/images/car_model/defaultcarimage-thumb.jpg [L]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

1) Remove ETage and Last-Modified using this code

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|html|htm|bmp)$">
Header unset Last-Modified
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

2) Compress text documents using **mod_deflate** and leave images and other audio/video files etc.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|png|rar|zip|mp3|mp4|flv|bmp)$ no-gzip
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
      Header append Vary User-Agent
   </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

If you want complete code to improve you site speed and 100 in YSlow then let me know i will provide you my htaccess code which i use for my site.

Comment: Didn't change anythings. I don't know what is problem. http://tuketiciyardim.com/webicerigi/

Comment: Try removing your RewriteCond and RewriteRule and using only my code. Currently your result shows that images are not found so that is probably incorrect url rewriting.

Comment: Sorry. Problem was database. I didn't write this script. I checked database and 2 string columns used for match. I added index and fixed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow to spped up your site.

1. Install the deflate module to compress the files.
2. Set the expiration time of the caching of the images
3. Load all th/e .js files one the page is loaded.
4. Put all the css files in one file
5. Add the .js files in one file if possible.
6. Make sure the size of the images is not very big

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/